# Could not access type BSONElement in package reactivemongo.bson.package

Tags: scala, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

Hi I am trying to compile a `play framework` application which uses the `reactivemongo` driver.

The `./activator compile` works great on my dev machine but gives me the following error on a remote ubuntu box. The `build.sbt` is exactly the same in both machines.

```
summer@nights:/var/jenkins/workspace/myApp$ ./activator compile
    [info] Loading project definition from /home/summer/.sbt/0.13/staging/38ee4fc38fad7d5824e0/myApp/project
    [info] Set current project to myApp (in build file:/var/jenkins/workspace/myApp/)
    [info] Compiling 8 Scala sources and 1 Java source to /home/summer/.sbt/0.13/staging/38ee4fc38fad7d5824e0/myApp/target/scala-2.11/classes...
    [error] missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'LowerImplicitBSONHandlers.class'.
    [error] Could not access type BSONElement in package reactivemongo.bson.package,
    [error] because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
    [error] missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
    [error] A full rebuild may help if 'LowerImplicitBSONHandlers.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of reactivemongo.bson.package.
    [error] one error found
    [error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
    [error] Total time: 16 s, completed Oct 7, 2016 10:19:29 AM
```

Comment: You are using different ReactiveMongo dependencies whose versions are not compatible. You should the coherency of your deps.

Comment: How would it run on my dev machine though if the build.sbt has not been changed?